# triggering events in multiple views

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm putting together an app using Backbone.js, which has two Views right now, an IndexView and a QuizPartial. The IndexView renders the bulk of the page (some graphs and whatnot), and it contains many QuizPartials. My issue is that when a user clicks a 'delete' link in one of the partials, the partial should be deleted and the appropriate model destroyed, while the IndexView renders a button to create a new quiz. However, I can't get the IndexView to respond to that event.

Code:

```
class QuizPartial extends Backbone.View
  tagName: "div"
  className: "quiz"
  events:
    "click a.delete": "delete_quiz" # Works fine

  initialize: -> @render()

  delete_quiz: ->
    if confirm "Are you sure you want to delete this test?"
      $(@el).remove()
      @model.destroy()
    false
```

And then the index view:

```
class IndexView extends Backbone.View
  tagName: "div"
  id: "quizzes_index"
  events:
    "click .quiz a.delete": "render_new_quiz_button" # Never fires

  initialize: -> @render()

  # etc...
```

Is there something I should be doing differently?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual UI event is done within the quiz view. You correctly remove the element and destroy the model. Now you have two choices:

- Have your IndexView listen for the "remove" event on your Quiz collection.
- Trigger a new event from your quiz view to notify whoever is listening